# Controller action that receives any data in xml json or form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0

I have a requirement to create a controller action that can accept any data in XML, JSON or form-urlencoded. However, I couldn't make it work.

If my action has a `Dictionary<string, object>` parameter, it works for JSON and XML data, but not for form-urlencoded. If my action has a `FormDataCollection` parameter, it works for form-urlencoded but not for JSON and XML.

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Default(FormDataCollection data /*Dictionary<string,object> data*/)
    {
        try
        {
            if (data == null)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { ErrorMessage = "The request body is empty" });

            //var collection = GetCollection(data); //used when data=Dictionary<string,object>
            var collection = data.ReadAsNameValueCollection();
            var agent = new ScriptingAgentClient();
            var parameters = ServiceAgentParameters.From(collection);

            var result = agent.Run(parameters);
            if (result.Error)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage, Exception = result.Exception });
            if (result.Data != null && result.Data.Count == 1) //result.Data is byte[]
            {
                //TODO: use the right Serializer
                var resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Data[0]);
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(resultString);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dict);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { ErrorMessage = "Unknown error" });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error handling request", ex);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { ErrorMessage = ex.Unwrap().Message });
        }
    }
```

`ScriptingAgentClient` will handle the data, whatever it may be.

If this isn't possible, how can I create two actions with same route where one will handle XML/JSON and another will handle form-urlencoded?

Note that I'm using **.net40** and I can't change that. Noteworthy to mention that this webapi is a self-hosted api that will run in a windows service.

Comment: Can you use javascript to submit the form ? That will allow you to serialize the form data into json before submission using javascript.

Comment: No... The api is agnostic about who/where it will be called... I need to support, json,xml and formdata.

Comment: @JobaDiniz Then you are going to have to either accept a string and parse the body based on the content type of create your own model binder to do the same thing (parse the incoming body based on content type)

Comment: Is there an example how to parse data using the right formatter/serializer based on content type? Because webapi already does this out of the box, but how can I do it myself? What classes should I look for? Does webapi exposes those methods/classes to handle the workload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work reading the `Request` instead of letting WebApi figuring it out:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Default()
    {
        try
        {
            NameValueCollection collection = Request.Content.IsFormData() ?
                Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result :
                GetCollection(Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>().Result);

            var parameters = ServiceAgentParameters.From(collection);

            var agent = new ScriptingAgentClient();
            var response = agent.Run(parameters);
            if (response.Error)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { ErrorMessage = response.ErrorMessage, Exception = response.Exception });

            if (response.Data != null && response.Data.Count == 1) //result.Data is List<byte[]>
            {
               //TODO: use the right Serializer
            var resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Data[0]);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(resultString);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dict);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { ErrorMessage = "Unknown error" });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error handling request", ex);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { ErrorMessage = ex.Unwrap().Message });
        }
    }
```